# Why does setuptools not understand git+https URLs?

Tags: python, git, setuptools

According to [Dependency section in the setuptools manual](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#dependencies-that-aren-t-in-pypi) `git` repository URLs can be specified in the `dependency_links` argument to `setup` with `git+URL`. Yet,

```
cd /tmp
mkdir py-test
cd py-test
touch __init__.py
```

and creation of a `setup.py` file with

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
from pkg_resources import parse_version

setup(
    name = "py-test",
    version = "1.0",
    packages = ["."],
    dependency_links = [
        "git+https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxPython.git"
    ],
    install_requires = ["wxPython"],
)
```

causes the error `Download error on git+https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxPython.git: unknown url type: git+https -- Some packages may not be found!` when I run `python setup.py build && sudo setup.py install`.

The installation of the package `python-setuptools-git` doesn't help.

I'm using `setuptools` 18.2 with `python` 2.7 on Ubuntu 15.04.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [setuptools docs](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html):

> In the case of a VCS checkout, you should also append #egg=project-version in order to identify for what package that checkout should be used

So the fix is just to append the `#egg=wxPython` fragment onto the end:

```
dependency_links = [
    "git+https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxPython.git#egg=wxPython"
]
```

Comment: FYI, if installing from pip, you need the `version` part, and it needs to be a number. e.g. `#egg=wxPython-1.0`